# creating a end of conversation for a google action using dialogflow and stop repeating the last response after a default fallback intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I made my first google action using dialogflow. But I have two problems:

1. I want to make an exit response.
   What I tried:

- Make a new intent called "exit"
- type in by trainingphrases: "stop" "end" "cancel" ....
- Response: "thanks, goodbye"
- checked the checkbox "make this intent as end of conversation."

But it is not working.
When I try this. the action is closed without my goodbye message.

2. When My default fallback Intent is triggered. After saying the fallback message the Google assistant repeats the last response..... I don't want that. is it possible to disable it in dialogflow?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daisy, It easier for us to help you when you ask 1 question per stackoverflow post. Please make another question for your fallback intent question as its difficult to give an answer to that question without some screenshots of what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `actions_event_cancel` exit [event](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/conversation-exits) to trigger a response when the user tries to exit your action.

Comment: Hello, I tried this. I made a new intent but in the even selector I only have 30 options like "welcome" and "google assistant welcome"...... but no "actions_intent_CANCEL" When I type it myself and go to integrations and "google assistant" I have a "test" link but then the test console of google actions opens. There is no update draft button". and I checked the box (auto preview changes)" already.

Comment: That's fine if you follow the steps it should update once you press Test. If it doesn't work, make sure you completed step 5: `Enable Set this intent as end of conversation.`. The intent won't trigger unless it actually ends the conversation.